# Laravel excluding resourceful functions in a clean way

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Currently I have these 4 resourceful routes in my `web.php` file.

```
Route::resource('campaigns', 'CampaignController')->except(['show']);
Route::resource('users', 'UserController')->except(['show']);
Route::resource('models', 'ModelController')->except(['show']);
Route::resource('trims', 'TrimController')->except(['show']);
```

And I can't help but wonder. Can't I add something to the `Route::resources` function to make it behave this way? This because they all have one thing in common. They `except()` the `show()` method.

It want to have something like this. (This example does not work because `resources()` does not have an `except()` method.

```
Route::resources([
    'campaigns' => 'CampaignController',
    'users' => 'UserController',
    'models' => 'ModelController',
    'trims' => 'TrimController'
])->except(['show']);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is already pretty old, but i just faced the same problem and solved it this way:

```php
Route::resources([
    'campaigns' => 'CampaignController',
    'users' => 'UserController',
    'models' => 'ModelController',
    'trims' => 'TrimController'
], [
    'except' => ['show']
    // you can set here other options e.g. 'only', 'except', 'names', 'middleware'
]);
```

According to source code, method `resources` is not chainable, because it returns `void`. But you still can pass the options into second argument of `resources`.

This is "Larawel-way" and you have not overwrite any vendor code.

Dig [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php) to get more info, how it works.

---

Note that if you want to exclude `show` method, but try to reach `/users/{user}` (HTTP `GET`) in browser, router will throw `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT, PATCH, DELETE.` error. It happens because router still has this route, but for `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE`. Then your application crashes.

So, maybe you want show HTTP 404 if someone accidentally goes to "show" page.
I prefer to add [fallback](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes) route (**this should be the last route of your routes!**)

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    abort(404);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own class that extends `Illuminate\Routing\Route` and implement your `resources` method like that:

```php
namespace App\Extends;

class Route extends Illuminate\Routing\Route {

   public function resources($routes, array $excepts) {
     foreach ($routes as $key => $value){
         $this->resource($key, $value)->except($excepts);
     }
   }

}
```

After you will need to bind your class in your service provider like this:

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Routing\Route', 'App\\Extends\\Route');
}
```

and call `resources` in **web.php** like that:

```php
Route::resources([
    'campaigns' => 'CampaignController',
    'users' => 'UserController',
    'models' => 'ModelController',
    'trims' => 'TrimController'
], ['show']);
```

**[EDIT 1]**

From **[laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)**

> You may register many resource controllers at once by passing an array to the resources method:

```php
Route::resources([
    'photos' => 'PhotoController',
    'posts' => 'PostController'
]);
```

But I don't know if you can call `->except(['show'])` like that

```php
Route::resources([])->except(['show'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to rewrite / override a function. My question was basically is this suported by Laravel at the moment. This is a nice solution though.

Comment: That's it I guess :). Thanks although I did not find what I wanted!

Comment: Thanks again for opening the gates of possibility. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about possibility then yes it's possible as above answer mentioned but by default you can't

Take a look at this file,

> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Route.php

```
 * @method static \Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration resource(string $name, string $controller, array $options = [])
 * @method static void resources(array $resources)
```